# Is there a way to find all the files that got created a specific time?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, time

I want to make a bash script in unix where the user gives a number between 1 and 24.then it has to scan every file in the directory that the user is and find all the files that got created the same time as the number.

I know that unix wont store teh birth time for most of the files.So I found that each file has crtime, which you can find with this line of code: `debugfs -R 'stat /path/to/file' /dev/sda2`
The problem is that i have to know every crtime so I can search them by the hour.

thanks in advance and sorry for the complicated explenation and bad english

Comment: It still depends on the filesystem; you're assuming ext4 if you rely on `crtime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop to execute `stat` for each file, then use `grep -q` to check whether the crtime matches the time given by the user. Since paths in `debugfs -R 'stat path'` do not necessarily correspond to paths on your system and there might be quoting issues, we [use inode numbers instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/569136/187122).

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
hour="$1"
for f in ./*; do
    debugfs -R "stat <$(stat -c %i "$f")>" /dev/sda2 2> /dev/null |
    grep -Eq "^crtime: .* 0?$hour:" &&
    echo "$f"
done
```

Above script assumes that your working directory is on an ext4 file systems on /dev/sda2. Because of `debugfs` you have to run the script as the superuser (for instance by using `sudo`). Depending on your system there might be an [alternative to `debugfs`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7563/187122) which can be run as a regular user.

Example usage:
Print all files and directories which were created between 8:00:00 am and 8:59:59 am.

```
$ ./scriptFromAbove 8
./some file
./another file
./directories are matched too
```

If you want to exclude directories you can add `[ -f "$f" ] &&` in front of `debugfs`.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the Quick response! 
unfortunately when I run your script it doesnt work for me...

I am very new and i cannot understand why.

I found this command `df -Th` which showed me that ext4 is /dev/sda1

so I changed your line to 

`debugfs -R "stat <$(stat -c %i "$f")>" /dev/sda1 1> /dev/null | `
Now everytime I run it using sudo (it says permission denied if i dont)
I get this message a lot of times: `debugfs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
`

Comment: Seems like you solved all problems yourself. `sudo` is required due to `debugfs`. Are there any problems left?

Comment: Wow you are quick!
The only message I get is `debugfs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)`

Comment: Strange, that message should be suppressed by `2> /dev/null`. Regarding the "missing" output: Did you make sure that there are actually files in the current directory created in the given hour? The following command should at least print `./testfile`: `touch testfile; sudo ./scriptFromThisAnswer $(date +%H)`.

Comment: yeees it works i changed some code from above and with the `touch testfile` it works
thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. You can [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to say thank you and close your question.

Answer (score 0):

The OP has already identified the issue that Unix system calls do not retrieve the file creation time - just the modification times (either mtime or ctime). Assuming this is acceptable substitution, an EFFICIENT way to find all the files in the current directory created on a specific hour is to leverage 'ls' and an awk filter.

```
#! /bin/sh
printf -v hh '%02d' $1
ls -l --time-style=long-iso | awk -v hh=$hh '+$7 == hh'
```

While this solution does not access the actual creation time, it does not require super user access (which is usually required for `debugfs`)